# Text recognition from an image in android

Tags: android

I have to implement Text Recognition feature in our APP but I am failed to do so. I implemented many codes for the same as OCR integration. but failed to achieve the desired. Please suggest a right solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? A fully working application?

Answer (score 1):

Tesseract is a good library and there is a JNI wrapper available:
http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/

I found this blog that might be useful -
http://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/using-tesseract-tools-for-android-to-create-a-basic-ocr-app/