# Google Play Vision: Define OCR Character Range?

Tags: android, google-play-services, ocr, vision

I'm using Google's `play-services-vision` to perform Optical Character Recognition (OCR) using the `TextRecognizer` class on the Android platform.

In the interest of performance, I would like to limit the range of characters possible for recognition to the expected range of my application. I don't know how to go about informing the `TextRecognizer` of this.

Currently, I am using a very basic implementation:

```
TextRecognizer t = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getActivity()).build();
```

I'm hoping for functionality reminiscent of the following, where the `TextRecognizer` would only be capable of returning characters in the range of `01234abc`:

```
t.setCharacterRange("01234abc");
```

If it is at all possible to define this *whitelist*, does anyone have any knowledge as to whether special characters can be configured for detection too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no function to *whitelist* only the specific characters you want to be recognized by [`TextRecognizer`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/text/TextRecognizer). You'll have to implement your own *checker/verifier* on the [`TextBlock`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/text/TextBlock) String value returned.

<sub>P.S. - Yup. I also think it's a lot of work.</sub>

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for letting me know. I assume special characters are a no-go too?

Comment: AFAIK, the `TextRecognizer` only recognize alphanumeric characters. Try to take a look around some other libraries, maybe there's one that suits your need. From what I've read from looking around, *Tesseract* looks promising. (See these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9466477/4625829, http://stackoverflow.com/a/36453469/4625829)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll be sure to take a look.

Comment: Cool. Good luck with your app. :)

Comment: See my quesiton as well https://stackoverflow.com/q/76651691/4134215